# java Oracle db eclipse TopLink RelationalDescriptor without primary key: is it possible?

Tags: java, primary-key, toplink

We use in the java project for our model the

```
org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.RelationalDescriptor
```

that is casted then to the `ClassDescriptor`. For the db table objects this is working properly. But for such Descriptors for the db views without primary key the method

```
org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project.addDescriptor(...);
```

raises the run-time error

```
RelationalDescriptor: The primary key fields are not set for this descriptor
```

What could be done to read such views to get then the `Vector<...>` collections?

Answer (score 1):

We use in the java project for our model the

org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor
for the db table objects, that are working properly. But for such Descriptors for the db views without primary key the method

org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Project.addDescriptor(...);
raises the run-time error

RelationalDescriptor: The primary key fields are not set for this descriptor
What could be done to read such views to get then the Vector<...> collections?

java primary-key toplink